# Facing error while starting anaconda navigator

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I installed anaconda today and while starting the navigator it crashed every time i tried reinstalling it 3 times and error comes every time following is the error:

OMimeDatabase: Error loading internal MIME data An error has been encountered at line 1 of : Premature end of document.:

Answer (score 0):

It is quite the usual error that may be caused due to incomplete installation or might be due to issues in internet connectivity may not do the complete installation.

Moreover, the source can also matter might be from where you are getting Anaconda have damaged product.

1. Firstly, you should verify the source from where you are downloading.
2. Uninstall the current one completely
3. Reinstall it and run that as administrator (This will probably help you)